# eclipse: plugin to call Maven - Update Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin to call the command that is executed when you Right click on a Maven Project and select "Maven" > "Update Project".

(This is part of a bigger plugin)

I can get command Service and from that I understand I can call ...

```
commandService.getCommand("org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.command.updateProject")
```

To get the command, but how do I control what project it is executed on?

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a [parameterized command](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/ParameterizedCommand.html) from your existing command. See the Eclipse wiki for [Executing a command with parameters](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Executing_a_command_with_parameters).